# What preprocessing.scale() do? How does it work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Python 3.5, preprocessing from sklearn

```
df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
X = np.array(df)
X = preprocessing.scale(X)
```

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.scale.html)?

Comment: yeah but I can't understand what it is doing to the values of X ?

Comment: I beleive it subtracts the mean and divides by the standard deviation of your dataset along a given axis.

Comment: here is [another link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#standardization-or-mean-removal-and-variance-scaling)  this can help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The preprocessing.scale() algorithm puts your data on one scale. This is helpful with largely sparse datasets. In simple words, your data is vastly spread out. For example the values of X maybe like so:

X = [1, 4, 400, 10000, 100000]

The issue with sparsity is that it very biased or in statistical terms skewed. So, therefore, scaling the data brings all your values onto one scale eliminating the sparsity. In regards to know how it works in mathematical detail, this follows the same concept of Normalization and Standardization. You can do research on those to find out how it works in detail. But to make life simpler the sklearn algorithm does everything for you !

Comment: After scaling this data will still be skewed. It will just be a lot closer to zero. Also an array of numbers cannot be biased unless there is some ground truth this is trying to represent.

Answer (score 1):

Scaling the data brings all your values onto one scale eliminating the sparsity and it follows the same concept of Normalization and Standardization.
To see the effect, you can call describe on the dataframe before and after processing:

```
df.describe()

#with X is already pre-proccessed 
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(X)
df2.describe()
```

You will see df2 has **0 mean** and the standard **variation of 1** in each field.

Answer (score 0):

preprocessing.scale() method is helpful in standardization of data points. It would divide by the standard deviation and substract the mean for each data point.

Comment: A bit misleading, in that it would subtract the mean of your points first, then divide by the standard deviation. Alternatively you can divide by the standard deviation, compute the new mean, and subtract that.